# Data structure to store sparse bit-field

Tags: algorithm, performance, hash, set, space-complexity

Dijkstra's algorithm requires a bit-field `settled` to decide wether a vertex has already been settled or not.

I currently use a bool-array (initialized to false) to achieve this.

I usually settle only a very small part of the graph before aborting the algorithm, hence only very few bits in the bit-field `settled` will be set to `true`.

What's the best way to not waste *O(N)* memory for `settled` in practice for Dijkstra's algorithm on sparse graphs (*O*(edges) = *O*(vertices))?

Comment: How do you define "best"?

Comment: Better in space and same in time for Dijkstra's alrogithm in practice.

Comment: You might try a hashset (amortized same complexity) or set (balanced tree; so logn vs. 1). If that's good depends on your access patterns of course (and is obviously slower than the dense approach).

Comment: That's what I already thought of ... what should I use in practice? A tree-structure might be faster (even if it is asymptotically slower than O(1)).

Comment: You will need to try it and it's easy to implement some wrapper so you can compare this easily. I did not check your algorithm, but if your algorithm will eventually visit (almost) all vertices (or to be more clear: if there is a huge visited-list at some state), you will just make it worse of course by this change.

Comment: In Java you could use BitSet class instead of boolean[], I guess there exists something similar for most languages.